# JENKINS: ERROR when I try to use an older JDK for a specific maven project

Tags: jenkins, java-7, maven-toolchains-plugin

I am using the Jenkins version 2.73-1.1 on a CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 server.

There are 3 different versions of JDK on the server:

```
[root @ jenkins java] # ll
total 12
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 16 27 Apr 16.25 default -> / usr / java / latest
drwxr-xr-x. 8 root root 4096 27 Mar 2013 jdk1.6.0_45
drwxr-xr-x. Root root 4096 11 Apr 2015 jdk1.7.0_80
drwxr-xr-x. 9 root root 4096 27 Apr 16.25 jdk1.8.0_131
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 22 27 apr 16.25 latest -> /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131
```

As shown in the pictures below, Jenkins is using the jdk1.8.0_131 version and in my project I specified to use JDK7.

[Jenkins setup Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Opyhz.jpg)

[Jenkins setup Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO9s1.jpg)

When I try to compile my project (`mvn clean deploy`), the build fails and I see this ERROR in log:

> [Vodafone] $ /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java -cp
>   /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-agent-1.11.jar:/opt/apache-maven-3.0.4/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar
>   org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main /opt/apache-maven-3.0.4
>   /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-3.10.jar
>   /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-1.11.jar
>   /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.11.jar
>   46349 <===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started ERROR:
>   ================================================================================ ERROR: Invalid project setup: jenkins/security/MasterToSlaveCallable :
>   Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 ERROR:
>   [JENKINS-18403][JENKINS-28294] JDK 'JAVA7' not supported to run Maven
>   projects. ERROR: Maven projects have to be launched with a Java
>   version greater or equal to the minimum version required by the
>   master. ERROR: Use the Maven JDK Toolchains (plugin) to build your
>   maven project with an older JDK. ERROR: Retrying with slave Java and
>   setting compile/test properties to point to /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_80.
>   ERROR:
>   ================================================================================ Established TCP socket on 38129 [Vodafone] $
>   /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/bin/java -cp
>   /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-agent-1.11.jar:/opt/apache-maven-3.0.4/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar
>   org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main /opt/apache-maven-3.0.4
>   /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-3.10.jar
>   /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-1.11.jar
>   /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.11.jar
>   38129 <===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started

Why Jenkins doesn't use jdk 7?

Answer (score 6):

As it is documented on the [maven project plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin) of Jenkins home page:

> Jenkins >= 2.54 requires Java 8 thus Maven jobs must be launched with Java >= 8

Luckily the best workaround is just mentioned in your stack trace:

> ... Use the **Maven JDK Toolchains (plugin)** to build your maven project with an older JDK...

In order to compile your project using java 7 and launch a successful Jenkins job using the current Jenkins version, I would recommend you use [toolchains plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-toolchains-plugin/toolchains/jdk.html) in 2 simple steps:

- Add **toolchains.xml** file to your **.m2** directory both on developers system and Jenkins server

  ```
   <toolchains>
     <toolchain>
       <type>jdk</type>
       <provides>
         <version>1.7</version>
         <vendor>openjdk</vendor>
       </provides>
       <configuration>
         <jdkHome>/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64</jdkHome>
       </configuration>
     </toolchain>
     <toolchain>
       <type>jdk</type>
       <provides>
         <version>1.8</version>
         <vendor>openjdk</vendor>
       </provides>
       <configuration>
         <jdkHome>/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64</jdkHome>
       </configuration>
     </toolchain> 
     [...]
   </toolchains>
  ```
- Add toolchain **plugin** to your project **pom** file

  ```
   <project>
     <build>
       <plugins>
         <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>1.1</version>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <goals>
                 <goal>toolchain</goal>
               </goals>
               </execution>
             </executions>
             <configuration>
               <toolchains>
                 <jdk>
                   <version>1.7</version>  
                   <vendor>openjdk</vendor>
                 </jdk>
               </toolchains>
             </configuration>
         </plugin>
       </plugins>
     </build>
   </project>
  ```

Finally, config your Jenkins job to use **jdk 8**, the toolchain will take care of compiling your project with **jdk 7**.

Answer (score 4):

Try configuring a Freestyle Job in Jenkins. You will need to select the "**Invoke top-level Maven targets**" build. I was having a similar problem. This worked for me.